# Unity 3D move object around orbit with user inputs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a spaceship which flies around planets orbit by this script:

```
Update() {
    transform.RotateAround(planet.transform.position, Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

But I don't understand how to add user inputs (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") and Input.GetAxis("Vertical")) to this script so user can control spaceship's movement. How can I move spaceship around orbit using user input (arrows) ?

EDIT:
Camer follows ship from behind. Ship is moved forward by some force (speed) on planet's orbit (to simplify, it's just a circle). I want user to be able to change direction of movement (left\right) like in the pucture (from D1 to D2).

[image: Example]

[image: Space Ship on planets orbit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task can be split into two parts. First is rotating the ship based on user input. The second is to change our method of orbiting to account for the rotation of the ship so that it moves in the direction that it is facing.

We can solve part one by using a `Transform.Rotate` call. Since we want the bottom of the ship to always face the planet, we want to rotate along the ship's "Up" axis. For our Input axis, the "Horizontal" will likely be the most intuitive. It will look something like this:

```
transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

For part two, it is important to realize that `Transform.RotateAround` uses the world space, and not the local space. By making it use the local space of the ship, it will account for the ship's rotation such that the ship will move in the direction that it is facing, rather than moving in an independent direction. We can do this by using the `Transform.TransformDirection` function. It will look something like this:

```
transform.RotateAround(planet.transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.up), speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Combining these in an update function worked for me in a quick test.

---

In addition, if we want the ship to strafe from side to side without doing any local rotation of the ship, we can do it with another `Transform.RotateAround` call, like so:

```
transform.RotateAround(planet.transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right), Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * strafeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

---

(Answer edited for question edit)

Comment: Thanks! But by changing speed component user can move ship only forward and back ward. But I want also change the direction\angle of movement by user input.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear from your description above. So you want the ship to move by its own force, as well as the separate gravitational force keeping it in orbit? To move the ship forward you will want something like  `transform.Translate(Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Vector3.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);`, and to rotate it you will want something like `transform.Rotate(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Vector3.right * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);` in addition to the current orbit code. If you update your description, I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Of course, manually moving the ship like this will change the shape of the orbit. If an accurate simulation is what you are after, you might want to consider something more advanced than RotateAround that will let you simulate orbits of any shape.

Comment: Clarified the question

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've modified my answer.

Comment: Thaks a lot for Ur help!